# Reading file byte by byte with ifstream::get

Tags: c++, ifstream

I wrote this binary reader after a tutorial on the internet. (I'm trying to find the link...)

The code reads the file byte by byte and the first 4 bytes are together the magic word. (Let's say MAGI!) My code looks like this:

```
std::ifstream in(fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
char *magic = new char[4];

while( !in.eof() ){
   // read the first 4 bytes
   for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
      in.get(magic[i]);
   }

   // compare it with the magic word "MAGI"
   if (strcmp(magic, "MAGI") != 0){
        std::cerr << "Something is wrong with the magic word: " 
                  << magic << ", couldn't read the file further! " 
                  << std::endl; 
        exit(1);
    }

   // read the rest ...
}
```

Now here comes the problem, when I open my file, I get this error output: 
`Something is wrong with the magic word: MAGI?, couldn't read the file further!` So there is always one (mostly random) character after the word MAGI, like in this example the character `?`! 
I do think that it has something to do with how a string in C++ is stored and compared with each other. Am I right and how can I avoid this?

PS: this implementation is included in another program and works totally fine ... weird.

Comment: `strcmp` expects a nul-terminated `char` array. Do `char * magic = new char[5]; magic[4]='\0';`

Comment: I thought C strings had to be null terminated? `'M','a','g','i',0x00`

Comment: Others have already answered your question. But I have a question for you - why are allocating memory dynamically for your array - why not `char magic[4];`?

Comment: [`while .eof` is almost always wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/istream-and-eof.html), and you're not even checking it before every read (even if that were how it should be done, which it' not).

Comment: Most of the codes above were copied and pasted from a tutorial I found on the internet. I'm quite a newbie, so I'm still learning a lot just by doing and asking questions. @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I am actually having some trouble with .eof, which I was bypassing with a trick. I'll have a better look at this. Thanks!

Comment: @streuguut: You never know what you're getting with these "tutorials" written by some random person on the internet. Prefer [a good, peer-reviewed book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strcmp assumes that both strings are nul-terminated (end with a nul-character). When you want to compare strings which are not terminated, like in this case, you need to use [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/) and tell it how many characters to compare (4 in this case).

```
if (strncmp(magic, "MAGI", 4) != 0){
```

When you try to use strcmp to compare not null-terminated char arrays, it can't tell how long the arrays are (you can't tell the length of an array in C/C++ just by looking at the array itself - you need to know the length it was allocated with. The standard library is not exempt from this limitation). So it reads any data which happens to be stored in memory after the char array until it hits a 0-byte.

**By the way:** Note the comment to your question by [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/), which is unrelated to the issue you are having now, but which hints a different bug which might cause you some problems later on.

Comment: I also tried @user93353's suggestion to allocate the memory `char magic[4];` instead of `char *magic= new char[4];`. And this time `strcmp(magic, "MAGI")` works fine. But I don't really understand the difference.

Comment: And there shouldn't be a difference. The only explanation I have is that because [the compiler uses different memory allocation strategies for dynamically and statically allocated memory](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/), it is more likely in the latter case that the byte after the char array is a nul-byte. But you can't rely on that. Either allocate an additional byte and set it to nul (`char magic[5]; magic[4] = '\0';`), or use strncmp.

Comment: ...or you screw those pesky c-style strings and use the object-oriented alternative [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string) instead.